Let's get critical: Jan 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Visual acuity and offset stimuli

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Grid cells : Between what is the correlation of autocorrelogram measured?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


Does your voice pitch affect your perceived authority?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


Relationship between oculometry/pupillometry and disorders of consciousness

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)


What is the difference between feeling sad and feeling unhappy?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)


What kind of memory it is?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)


Are there any circumstances where schizophrenia or bipolar disorder are not lifelong?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is there a good entry-level tutorial for SPM?

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)


What evidence is there for a correlation between being tightly focused on a problem and only using one part of your brain?

Net Score: -7 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 7)


What is the relation between fun and motivation? Are they the same?

Net Score: -10 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 10)


Happy to see my answers were received 5,5,3 ! However, as I reviewed them myself I must say these scores have been biased :) For a next round of self-eval I think self-answers should be excluded. Admittedly I didn't max my own answers always, but never really shot them to pieces either, obviously.

I have a recommendation for future evaluations:
Site self-eval should automatically skip those questions in which the evaluator at hand answered it himself or herself. In other words, an avaluator should never have to review his/her own answer to prevent bias. 
